# LCD Display with FPC to Arduino

Tags: arduino, pcb, lcd, arduino-uno, fpc

I’m very new. My game is push button, but it’s important that the display is transparent.

I have this LCD screen. ([data sheet](https://newhavendisplay.com/content/specs/NHD-C12864B2Z-RN-FBW.pdf)) I was going to connect it to my uno using this PCB. But it didn’t fit into the socket. Did it not fit because I needed one with more pins like the third picture?

My plan was to solder it like this video

[YouTube solder video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gi-44SDc4ds)

But then I noticed his adapter didn’t even have one of those sockets.

Can someone more knowledgeable than myself tell me if I’m on the right track and maybe link me to something that will work with my project?

I’m also willing to completely change how I’m going about this. (If maybe anyone knows of any transparent LCD displays that can hook up to my Arduino easier than this)

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From datasheet: Recommended LCD connector: 27 pins, 0.5mm Pitch FFC That's what you need to look for in an adapter.

Comment: Thank you! Also can I use one with 30 pins even though there are 27?

Comment: I can't tell. If the alignment / pitch is the same, it'll work.The 27 pin are rare, and any adpter. nothing found.